# Prove and disprove the sequence of function converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

We have $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ and $g_n(x)=x^n$. Let sequences of functions be $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ Prove that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, but $(g_n)$ does not converge to any functions uniformly.

For $(f_n)$, I have,

Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N > \frac{x}{\epsilon}$. Then, for any $n \ge N$, we have

$\|f_n(x) - 0\|_\infty$ = $\|f_n(x)\|_\infty$ = $\|\frac{x}{n}\|_\infty$ = sup$|\frac{x}{n}| \ge \frac{x}{n}$

Here, since we need to take the supremum I don't know how to show it is less than $\epsilon$. Can I show that the supremum is equal to $\frac{x}{n}$?

For $(g_n)$m I have,

$\|g_n(x) - g_x(x)\|_\infty$ = sup$|g_n(x) - g_x(x)| \ge |g_n(x) - g_x(x)| = x^n-x^x \ge 0$

Here, also I don't know how to continue. Can I say that the equation may be greater than some $\epsilon$ so that the sequence does not converge?

Comment: What is the domain of definition for the given functions where you are looking for uniform convergence ?

Answer (score 0):

For the second sequence of functions, note that each function is continuous. If they converged uniformly then they would converge to a continuous function. However, they don't converge to a continuous function. To see this, note that $g_n(1)=1$ for all $n$, while $g_n(x)\to 0$ for all $0\leq x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:

$$|f_n(x)-0| = |\dfrac{x}{n}-0| = \left |\dfrac{x}{n}\right| \leq \left|\dfrac{x}{N}\right| \leq\left|\dfrac{x}{\dfrac{x}{\epsilon}}\right| = \epsilon$$ so $$|f_n(x)-0|< \epsilon$$

For the second one, I prefer to use Cauchy sequences: $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m,n >N , |x_n-x_m|>\epsilon$. Let's also $n>m$ and (just for arbitrary use, let's $x>0$)

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| = |x^n-x^m| = |x^m||x^{n-m}-1| = |x^m||x-1||\sum_{i\leq n-m-1}x^i|\geq |x^N||x-1||\sum_{n-N-1}x^i|\geq|x^N||x-1|$$

so, taking $0<\epsilon<|x^N||x-1|$ you can conclude...

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it carefully. The definition of uniform convergence is $fn \to f$ respect to $L^\infty$, which is uniform norm. And it means you have to take supremum of the sequence. So I think the first one is not that easy....

Comment: But my point still stands: $\|\dfrac{x}{n}\|_\infty = \sup \|\dfrac{x}{n}\| = |\dfrac{x}{N}| $ , then you can use my same principle...